# Global.asax methods are not triggered

Tags: wcf, ssl, tls1.2, global-asax, autostart

After adding SSL to my WCF service, `global.asax` methods like `Apllication_Start` or `Application_BeginRequest` stopped being triggered. The service itself launches normally with no exception. New code added below (and ofc some configurations in IIS Manager:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="SomeService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="secureBehavior">                       
            <endpoint 
                address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" 
                contract="SomeService.IService" />
            <endpoint 
                address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>          
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="secureBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Buddy, have you tried to invocate the service over https protocol? As far as I know, the service by default is also supported over HTTP protocol even though Basichttpbinding does not configure. I suggest you check whether the client invocation based on https protocol.

Comment: Tried it. Still nothing